# cant find Isam installable CSV Files

Tags: vb.net, excel, csv

Hey I am having a problem taking an excel spread sheet and inserting it into a data-grid in Visual Studio 2013 I was wondering if anyone could give me a hand.

Here is the code I have at the moment.

getting the error Could not find installable ISAM only when I have clicked on the csv fle iut works for ll the other files?

```
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()


    Dim filePath As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(filePath)
    Dim header As String = If(rbHeaderYes.Checked, "YES", "NO")
    Dim conStr As String, sheetName As String

    conStr = String.Empty
    Select Case extension

        Case ".xls"
            'Excel 97-03
            conStr = String.Format(Excel03ConString, filePath, header)
            Exit Select

        Case ".xlsx"
            'Excel 07
            conStr = String.Format(Excel07ConString, filePath, header)
            Exit Select

        Case ".csv"
            'CSV
            conStr = String.Format(ExcelCsv, filePath, header)
            Exit Select
    End Select

    'Get the name of the First Sheet.
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            Dim dtExcelSchema As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
            sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using

    'Read Data from the First Sheet.
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
            Using oda As New OleDbDataAdapter()
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                cmd.CommandText = (Convert.ToString("SELECT * From [") & sheetName) + "]"
                cmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                oda.SelectCommand = cmd
                oda.Fill(dt)
                con.Close()

                'Populate DataGridView.
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Just use Jet OLEDB: in your connection string.

Comment: Use:  Dim path As String = "C:\Users\richard\Dropbox (SortmyPC)\Projects\YourCompanyMobiles\Smaple Import Data.xlsx"

Comment: You can use this connection string to use the Office 2007 OLEDB driver (ACE 12.0) to connect to older 97-2003 Excel workbooks.
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myOldExcelFile.xls;
Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES";

"HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.

Comment: @CristiC777 I have changed my code as I am looking to load a Folder but Im not I am still getting the error but only when I load a csv file works for all the others? any ideas?

Comment: edit/post new code and error with what type of files? what "all the others" fiels ? and put a BreakPoint in :  'Read Data from the First Sheet >> cmd.CommandText = and check if is ok . Also check what is in : Excel03ConString, Excel07ConString ..